# Why my lambda expression cannot automatically cast the parameter to specific class?

Tags: java, lambda

```java
public CreditStationingResponse queryStationingResponse(CreditStationingRequest request) {
    return runInSessionScope(req -> {
        return cbuBhUniversalService.queryStationingData(req);
    }, request);
}
```

Idea told me that there is an error:

> 'queryStationingData(com.alibaba.fin.xyd.api.credit.request.CreditStationingRequest)' in 'com.alibaba.fin.tfp.application.credit.CbuBhUniversalService' cannot be applied to '(P)'

And the definition of runInSessionScope is shown as bellow:

```java
public static <P extends IBizInstance, R> R runInSessionScope(Function<P, R> function, P param) {
    return runInSessionScope(function, param, ignoreTmfSessionScope);
}
```

Comment: Please show the definition of `queryStationingData`.

Comment: does `CreditStationingRequest` `extends` or `implements` `IBizInstance`?

Comment: You're asking the compiler to figure out what the type parameters `<P, R>` are. You've given it what `R` is using `req`, but not `P`. At the same time, the compiler needs to infer what the data types of parameters to `Function` are. In other words, the compiler needs to infer data types in both ways. And that's too much to ask.

Answer (score 1):

I check the definition of the CreditStationingRequest, and it is not extended from  IbizInstance, which leads to the error.